# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception arriving in java android while using list view(typed array)

Tags: java, android

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    String str = "weblinks_" + i;
    try {
        details = res.getIdentifier(str, "array", getPackageName());
        file = true;
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        file = false;
    }
    if (file) {
        typedArray = res.obtainTypedArray(details);
        for (int k = 0; k < typedArray.length(); k++) {
            MenuItem = typedArray.getString(k);
            if (k == 0) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(MenuItem));
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my strings file

```
<array name="weblinks_1">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Home</item>
</array>
 <array name="weblinks_2">
    <item>wallet</item>
    <item>wallet</item>
</array>
  <array name="weblinks_3">
    <item>Recharge</item> 
    <item>recharge</item> 
</array>
<array name="weblinks_4">
    <item>Account</item>
    <item>account</item>
</array>
 <array name="weblinks_5">
    <item>Notifications</item>
    <item>notifications</item>
</array>
<array name="weblinks_6">
    <item>Privacy</item>
    <item>privacy</item>
</array>
<array name="weblinks_7">
    <item>Facebook</item>
    <item>facebook</item>
</array>
<array name="weblinks_8">
    <item>Twitter</item>
    <item>Twitter</item>
</array>
```

Now what my problem is getting array index out of bounds exception and app getting crashed.
The code above can shows that weblinks_1,weblinks_2,weblinks_3....up to n, but if i remove an array item from strings i am getting arrayIndexOutofBounds exception
Please any one help to solve this...regards

Comment: Probably it has something to do with your hard coded values like the 10 in your for loop. `for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){`

Comment: So are you saying the app crashes just like that? or does it crash only when you remove an array item?

Comment: Exactly you are right, when i remove an array from strings i am getting probably two errors 1.ResourceNotFoundException 2.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove boolean file variable and do the change as below.It will handle the Resource.NotFoundException

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
                String str = "weblinks_" + i;
                try {
                    details =this.getResources().getIdentifier(str, "array", this.getPackageName());

                    typedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(details);
                    for (int k = 0; k < typedArray.length(); k++) {
                        MenuItem = typedArray.getString(k);
                        if (k == 0) {
                            Log.e("String from" + str,MenuItem);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {

                }


            }
```

and for **arrayIndexOutofBounds exception** need more code plus the logcat report